# how to limit traffic if port different than 8080?

Tags: linux, networking, security, firewall, iptables

I'm using this rules to slow down nmap scan

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

It works well , but the port 8080 have big activity and I want to ignoe it in the hitcount.
I want to have somethingn like that:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp **--dport!=8080** -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to slow do a nmap scan? sound like security by obscurity to me.

Comment: Yes it is . Is this a bad idea ?

Comment: so, what *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: This rules work precfectly and i want to make an exception for some ports like 8080 .

Comment: you'll find that you will slow down legitimate traffic too.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid by adding an exception for some ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using either by writing your rules like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp ! --dport 8080 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp ! --dport 8080 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

or alternatively, you can add new rules for the excluded ports (**BEFORE your rules**):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

The second way will make it easier for you to add more exceptions.

Comment: so you think nmap doesn't scan on 8080 first? I.e it's in it's top port lists?